# Is 'c'è' or 'ci sono' used with "un sacco di"

Tags: verbs, agreement

Is it correct to use 'c'è' or 'ci sono' with the idiomatic 'un sacco di'?

I have heard the expression 'ci sono un sacco di belle ragazze / bei ragazzi qui a Roma'. This struck me as odd that the person didn't make the verb agree with the singular "bag / sack" instead of the plural *ragazze / ragazzi*

What should the verb *esserci* agree with: the *sacco* or the *ragazze*?

Comment: 'ci sono' is correct. &nbsp; &nbsp;

Comment: Most Italian speakers would agree, but this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The theoretical correct form would indeed be “c'è un sacco di...”, since “sacco” is singular. But Italian language, since its onset, is very tolerant of the so called *accordo* (or *concordanza*) *a senso*, i.e. having the verb agree with the meaning of the subject, rather than with its actual number, especially with some very used collective nouns or phrases (*un sacco*, *una massa*, *un mucchio*, *un (bel) po'*, *un milione*...).

If you read Italian, you can read some about it [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/): «Con la terza persona [plurale], in genere un soggetto plurale o la presenza di più soggetti coordinati prevede l’accordo alla terza plurale. Deviazioni da questo principio sono di due tipi. Da un lato, un soggetto singolare può indurre un accordo al plurale, specialmente nel caso dei nomi collettivi che ricorrono come testa di sintagmi nominali complessi. In questi casi l’accordo può essere sia con il nome testa collettivo, sia con il nome dipendente al plurale (il cosiddetto accordo a senso):

(11) a. è venuta una massa di amici

b. sono arrivati un mucchio di invitati»

Comment: +1, and it's always good to remind that "la gente dicono" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I've never thought of that maybe because I've learn the expression before the grammar. Just consider "un sacco di" an abstract concept since many girls can't stay inside a bag.
So replace in your mind "un sacco di" with "molti/e". If it is a real concept you can use "C'è un sacco di patate" or "Ci sono due sacchi di patate".