# Accordo con soggetti del tipo "n milioni di..." o "un milione di..."

Tags: gender, agreement, grammatical-number

A proposito di  [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12804/), mi è venuto il dubbio su come si deve fare l'accordo in frasi il cui soggetto è della forma  "*n* milioni di..." o "un milione di...". So che a volte possono esserci due possibilità dipendendo dal fatto se si fa o no la cosiddetta concordanza *ad sensum*. Tuttavia, per frasi di questo tipo, non mi è per niente chiaro come si fa l'accordo e quando si può scegliere tra questi due modi di farlo.

Per chiarezza, divido il post in tre parti che numererò 1), 2) e 3).

1) Per cominciare, consideriamo il caso di una frase con un verbo coniugato con l'ausiliare "essere", come, ad esempio, questa:

> Tre milioni di persone sono andate in vacanza.

È così come si fa l'accordo del participio con il soggetto, con "andate" femminile plurale perché "persone" è femminile plurale? Dovrebbe invece accordarsi con "milioni", che è maschile plurale, cioè, in questo modo?

> Tre milioni di persone sono andati in vacanza.

Sono ammesse tutte e due?

2) Possiamo prendere in considerazione anche una frase con un predicato nominale. Per esempio,

> Trecento milioni di persone sono analfabete.

Ho accordato l'aggettivo "analfabete" con "persone" e, per questa ragione, l'ho messo al femminile plurale. Ma potrei (dovrei?) farlo con "milioni", maschile, in questa maniera?

> Trecento milioni di persone sono analfabeti.

E sarebbe  lo stesso con un soggetto del tipo "un milione di...":

> Un milione di persone sono analfabete

versus

> Un milione di persone è analfabeta.

3) Un'altra situazione da esaminare sarebbe quella di una frase con un soggetto del tipo "un milione di..." e un predicato verbale: come si accorda il verbo con il soggetto in questo caso? Se il soggetto è "un milione di persone", per esempio, la concordanza del verbo si deve fare con "persone" (cioè, plurale) o con "milione" (cioè, singolare)? Sono ammissibili ambedue le opzioni? Ad esempio, dobbiamo scrivere

> Un milione di persone dovrà lasciare il proprio paese

o

> Un milione di persone dovranno lasciare il proprio paese

oppure si accettano ambedue?

Infatti, questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)) riporta:

> un soggetto singolare *può* indurre un accordo al plurale, specialmente nel caso dei nomi collettivi che ricorrono come testa di sintagmi nominali complessi. In questi casi l’accordo può essere sia con il nome testa collettivo, sia con il nome dipendente al plurale (il cosiddetto accordo *a senso*):
>   
>   (11) a. è venuta una massa di amici
>   
>   b. sono arrivati un mucchio di invitati

Quindi, se "un milione" è da considerarsi un nome collettivo come "un mucchio" o "una massa", allora è chiaro che la risposta alla domanda 3) è che i due modi di fare l'accordo sopra spiegati sono ammessi. Prendendo l'esempio "è venuta una massa di amici" in cui il participio "venuta" s'accorda con "massa" (cioè, al femminile), si può anche dedurre la risposta alla domanda 1): la concordanza si può fare in ambedue le maniere esposte.

Tuttavia, non sono completamente sicura che "un milione" sia un nome collettivo come quelli menzionati nell'articolo della Treccani oppure sia da considerarsi semplicemente un numerale come "trecentomila" o "dieci".

Comment: “Un milione di” è un numerale. Come si dice “cento persone sono andate in vacanza”, altrettanto si dice per un milione. La sfortunata presenza della preposizione può far dire ai grammatici che la costruzione è errata, perché il soggetto è “un milione”. Ma “un milione di persone è andato in vacanza” mi farebbe pensare a un grosso pacco di persone. Accettabili entrambe le costruzioni.

Comment: In castigliano (e anche nella varietà di catalano che parlo io) non abbiamo verbi coniugati con l'ausiliare "ser" (essere), ma l'accordo di un predicato nominale con un soggetto del tipo "n millones de personas" si può fare soltanto con "personas", cioè, al femminile. Per il caso del soggetto "un millón de personas" e un predicato verbale, quello che si usa di più è fare l'accordo con "personas", cioè, coniugare il verbo al plurale.

Comment: Non sono completamente sicura se l'accordo con "millón" (cioè, coniugare il verbo al singolare) sia anche ammesso. Ho questo dubbio proprio a causa del fatto che "un millón" sia un numerale (si può certamente dire "un centenar de personas tendrá..." con il verbo al singolare). Ho posto la domanda su Spanish.SE, ma, per il momento non si è riusciti a trovare una risposta soddisfacente. Ma anche con "un centenar de personas" come soggetto, si usa di più accordare il verbo al plurale. Cioè, la concordanza *ad sensum* è quella che si usa di più. In catalano è simile.

Comment: Se dovessi scommettere come concorderebbe un campione casuale della popolazione dovendo scegliere tra “un milione di persone è andato” e “un milione di persone sono andate” punterei decisamente sulla seconda. Anche in italiano si usa “un centinaio”, ma il discorso è lo stesso.

Comment: Sì, @egreg, ma la domanda sarebbe: la prima si usa veramente? Si può usare?

Comment: La questione si pone anche per vari altre locuzioni: “la maggior parte/maggioranza di”, “un sacco di”, “un po' di” etc. Anche in questo sono accettabili entrambe le concordanze, ed empiricamente direi che, almeno con “po'” e “sacco”, prevalga di fatto il plurale.

Comment: Sì, @DaG: se n'era parlato [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3593). Il mio problema è che non sono completamente sicura che "un milione" sia un nome collettivo come "un sacco" o "una decina", o sia da considerarsi semplicemente un numero come "trecentomila" o "dieci". E, infatti, adesso ho lo stesso dubbio nelle mie lingue: su Spanish.SE c'è stato certo interesse per la domanda, ma finora nessuno è stato in grado di chiarirlo (la domanda è là da 4 giorni).

Comment: Non c'è dubbio che “milione” sia un sostantivo: vedi i dizionari, o Serianni (VI.2). I normali numerali in italiano sono invece, in prima approssimazione, aggettivi. Credo che di fatto prevalga la concordanza a senso, ma non più che per “un sacco” etc., anzi forse di meno. Per il poco che vale, googlando per esempio “un milione di persone è”, in mezzo a casi spurî, qualcosa si trova: “un milione di persone è dove in teoria non potrebbe essere”, “più di un milione di persone è sceso in piazza”, “Un milione di persone è pronto ad invadere l'Area 51” e così via.

Comment: @DaG:  Ah, ecco: «Oltre un milione di ettari nella peni­sola è incolto» ([Carducci](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000511.jpg)). Tuttavia, per le altre domande, continuo a non sapere se la risposta è che ci sono queste due possibilità d'accordo.

Comment: @DaG: veramente non è come avevo detto nel commento precedente. Diciamo che per il momento ho chiare le risposte alle domande 1) e 3) (ma, mi dispiace, non grazie all'unica risposta alla domanda), ma non quella alla domanda 2).

Comment: @Charo: Personalmente, entrambe le frasi del caso 2) non mi suonano molto bene; se dovessi scrivere una cosa del genere la riformulerei (per esempio, “Ci sono trecento milioni di persone analfabete”, o in un altro modo a seconda di che cosa voglio dire di preciso).

Comment: Mmm... interessante, @DaG. Ecco questa frase in [castigliano](https://books.google.es/books?id=ptMbO0Uk_doC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=%22Dos+millones+de+personas+est%C3%A1n): "Quatro millones de personas están expuestas a...". Quindi, se voglio dire lo stesso in italiano, "Quattro milioni di persone sono esposte a questo fenomeno" non suona bene e dovrei invece dire "Ci sono quattro milioni di persone esposte a questo fenomeno"? E potrei dire, per esempio, "la metà dei cassetti erano vuoti" o "la maggior parte dei suoi figli erano alti"?

Comment: @Charo: Io cerco di evitare situazioni così usando altre formulazioni (“...erano per la maggior parte alti” e simili). Ciò detto, c'è chi è più sensibile e chi meno a queste (s)concordanze, e forse cambia anche in base a cosa si sta dicendo, se per esempio l'aggettivo che segue si presta meglio o peggio a essere detto di singole persone o di grandi gruppi (tanto per dire una fanfaronata, mi suona un po' come le grandezze intensive ed estensive in fisica).

Comment: @DaG: Ho colto più o meno l'idea e sapere spiegare bene tutto questo sarebbe una risposta alla domanda. Secondo l'unica risposta che c'è adesso, sembrerebbe che si possa dire "Trecento milioni di persone sono analfabeti" o "Un milione di persone è analfabeta", che, a pensarci meglio, anche a me non mi suonano per niente bene: i milioni possono imparare a leggere? Invece, avrebbe senso dire "il gruppo di turisti era folto", ma suona meglio "era un gruppo folto di turisti".

Comment: @Charo ho capito che non accetti "Un milione di persone è analfabeta" perché in Spagnolo non si dice. In effetti "un milione" non può essere analfabeta, così come tante persone non entrano in un sacco. Ma "un milione di persone" è diverso da "un milione" come "un sacco di persone" è diverso da "un sacco". Il tuo dubbio è simile a quello di un italiano che cerca di tradurre "rendere possibile" in Inglese, e scrive "make possible", ma in Inglese si scrive "make *it* possible". È così e basta, che si conoscano le ragioni o no.

Comment: Considera anche la frase "La totalità degli italiani comprende l'Italiano". Diresti tu "La totalità degli italiani comprendono l'Italiano"? Riguardo al folto gruppo di turisti, le due frasi che citi sono molto diverse, cambia l'articolo (cosa non da poco). "il gruppo di turisti era folto" è una frase perfetta e *non la si può* esprimere diversamente senza modificarne, anche solo sottilmente, il senso.

Comment: @DaG: Mi sono presa la libertà di spiegare alcune delle idee e delle informazioni che hai escritto qui in commenti alla [domanda simile a questa su Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34593).

Comment: @DaG: Allora, se ho capito bene la risposta qui sotto (e il commento che dice "è così e basta"), posso dire senza problema "un milione di persone è analfabeta", "una decina dei visitanti è turista", "la maggior parte dei suoi figli è alta", "un centinaio di cittadine è ricco" o "il gruppo di turiste giapponese sono folte"? Non riesco a convincermi di questo, ma può darsi che in italiano si dica così.

Comment: Charo: Sono tutte frasi che suonano piuttosto strane e che io non scriverei. Quando ha senso farlo, io personalmente preferisco le concordanze letterali (“un centinaio di cittadini si è recato dal sindaco”) ma se, come negli esempi, si parla proprio di qualità dei singoli elementi dell'insieme, riformulerei in altro modo (“i suoi figli sono per la maggior parte alti” e così via).

Comment: Grazie, @DaG: questo aspetto è la parte della risposta che non mi convince. Veramente, anche a me tutte queste frasi non  suonano per niente bene. Però (a giudicare dai voti), altri utenti affermano che si usano, "è così e basta". Avevo pensato di scrivere un commento con un link a questa sotto la domanda di Spanish.SE, ma non sono del tutto sicura sia una buona idea.

Comment: @DaG: Frase dal *Pugno chiuso* di Boito: «Già mezzo milione era contato, già settecento mila fiorini erano contati, già era contato quasi l'intero milione di fiorini, [...]». Si tratta di passive (caso che non ho contemplato), ma è interessante vedere come con "mezzo milione" e "l'intero milione di fiorini" l'accordo del verbo si fa al singolare (non avrebbe senso farlo al plurale). Invece, con "settecento mila fiorini" si deve fare al plurale. È un'altra conferma di quello che hai detto in un tuo commento: "milione" è un sostantivo che si comporta in modo diverso di un numerale cardinale.

Comment: A proposito, si tratta di un bel racconto  (anche se con qualche stereotipo che si dovrebbe evitare, ma rispecchia la mentalità del tempo). È stato interessante scoprire la sfaccettatura di scrittore di Boito, che non conoscevo (per me era un compositore e un librettista).

Comment: @Charo: Grazie per la segnalazione!

Comment: @DaG: Se ne parla su [questo articolo](https://www.academia.edu/4720757/L_assetto_dell_italiano_delle_traduzioni_in_un_corpus_giornalistico_Aspetti_qualitativi_e_quantitativi?auto=download&email_work_card=download-paper). Da quanto ho capito, si hanno sempre le due possibilità d'accordo, con un'eccezione. Per *un milione* nel corpus studiato hanno trovato: «I numerali ‘singolari’, come *un milione*, *un miliardo*, *una decina*, *dozzina* (ci siamo
limitati a questi quattro), in genere prediligono il verbo al singolare, ma sembrano subire una certa influenza del contesto in cui sono inseriti».

Comment: L'eccezione è questa: «in presenza del verbo *essere* in funzione di copula, l’accordo al
plurale risulta obbligatorio quando la parte nominale del predicato è costituita
da un sostantivo» (forse anche con altri verbi in funzione di copula che non hanno considerato perché hanno spiegato che sono rari nel corpus studiato). Tuttavia, nel corpus analizzato si è riscontrato che c'è «una più forte tendenza alla concordanza *ad sensum* quando il predicato nominale comprende una parola classificabile sia come
sostantivo che come aggettivo, ma anche quando si tratti di un aggettivo tout court».

Comment: Quindi, se ho capito bene, si deve dire, per esempio, "un milione dei morti nella guerra erano soldati". Per l'esempio con "analfabeta" che ho fatto nella domanda sembra si usi di più la concordanza *ad sensum*.

Comment: So che si tratta di una domanda difficile, però: la domanda analoga a questa su Spanish.SE è stata meglio accolta (in questo momento è la mia domanda su quel sito con più voti e, nell'elenco di domande "unanswered" ordinate per numero di voti, appare al secondo posto), ma continua senza nessuna risposta  con voti positivi (ma nessuno si è arrabbiato o ha parlato di "dubbi sbagliati").

Answer (score -1):

Secondo me esistono vari gradi di "numeralità" nelle varie locuzioni
possibili. Il classico numerale (tre, venti, duemila) è un aggettivo, come
dice Dag, e non dà problemi, ma con numeri più grandi il sistema non
funziona più e occorre introdurre sostantivi (per esempio "un milione").

Nel caso di "un milione" s'introduce perciò una particella in più che,
ambiguamente, può essere considerata un numerale ma può sembrare un articolo;
inoltre, mentre si dice "tre persone/cose/telefoni", usando "milione" occorre aggiungere
una particella "di" e dire "un milione *di* persone/cose/telefoni". Ancora,
la costruzione con queste parole fa diventare maschili i soggetti femminili;
per conto mio può essere accettato perché tradizionalmente il maschile
è più generale o indeterminato ("gli scienziati" o "i politici" rappresentano
la categoria, "le scienziate" indica solo le studiose femmine), ma ultimamente
si discute anche di questo (vedi sindaco/sindaca).

Questa discontinuità, secondo me,
è un limite dell'Italiano, ed è presente anche in altre lingue: probabilmente
il motivo è che le lingue si formano prima di avere l'esigenza di trattare
grandi numeri, e infatti certe lingue primitive "sanno contare" solo fino
a tre, o cinque, o giù di lì (servirebbe una citazione ma sul momento
non sono in grado di fornirla).

A questo punto occorre decidere se "un milione", oppure "un migliaio", siano
numerali oppure nomi collettivi simili a "mucchio" o "branco". E non è finita:
perché si può dire "due milioni" e "due migliaia" proprio come si direbbe
"due mucchi". Il meccanismo pare ricorsivo ("un migliaio di milioni di gruppi"). Inoltre, come nota Egreg, "un milione di persone ha fatto..." comunica un senso di ammucchiamento, mentre "un milione di persone hanno fatto" mantiene maggiormente l'individualità.

La concordanza "a senso" (https://it.quora.com/Cosa-significa-concordanza-a-senso?share=1,
https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/concordanza)
è, secondo me, un'eccezione alla grammatica volta
a facilitare la costruzione delle frasi, ed è comparsa e stata accettata dopo
che nei discorsi comparvero i grandi numeri; però sovente stride.

Ci sono altre forme ambigue di "numeralità": "il 70% delle persone ..." è,
semanticamente, un numero preciso ma, di nuovo, grammaticalmente riporta al
problema del milione/migliaio/ventina eccetera, cioè la possibile discordanza
di genere e/o numero fra il soggetto grammaticale e quello semantico o comunque
inteso. Infine ci sono forme "poco numerali" come "un mucchio", "una quantità", "la maggior parte"
e simili che, nell'intenzione, esprimono numeri ma in modo impreciso; secondo
me poi, "una ventina" ha meno "numeralità" di "un milione" ma più di "un mucchio":
perché altrimenti si direbbe "venti" invece di "una ventina". Per non parlare poi di "dozzina": "una dozzina di rose è rossa" oppure "una dozzina di rose sono rosse"? Di nuovo, come dice Egreg, le frasi paiono giuste tutt'e due, ma danno un'impressione  diversa.

A me le frasi semplici che usano la concordanza a senso danno solitamente un po' fastidio;
le frasi più complicate meno, forse perché perdo il filo o forse
perché, alla fine, la concordanza a senso aiuta a capire meglio, pur con
il costo di un errore formale.

Una possibile risposta potrebbe essere: "si usi la concordanza esatta quando si usano
termini con poca "numeralità", quindi "un mucchio di persone è andato in vacanza",
"un migliaio di scatole si è rotto", "una ventina di lupi si aggira nel territorio"; e si
usi la concordanza a senso quando il termine ha grande "numeralità": "un milione di
persone sono andate", "il 70% delle matite sono nere" (ma questa stride, allora 70%
è più un nome collettivo che un'indicazione di quantità?).

Sono quasi certo che evitare la concordanza a senso sia la strada più sicura, anche se
in alcuni casi può risultare strana (non a me, di solito); d'altra parte ci sono
peculiarità nell'Italiano che non destano dubbi, ma solo perché l'uso è affermato e
non c'è la variabilità dei numerali di cui stiamo parlando ora. Sul momento non mi vengono
in mente esempi migliori ma, per dire, è scontato che si dica "dito" al singolare e "dita"
al plurale, oppure che la frase "Perché succede" possa essere una domanda o un'affermazione e la
distinzione si può fare solo con segni d'interpunzione o prosodia, o ancora perché
la frase "Non ho niente" indica mancanza piuttosto che la negazione della mancanza.

================ AGGIORNAMENTO ==============

Il libro dell'Accademia della Crusca, *"l'Italiano // 1. Bada (a) come scrivi"* (ISBN 978-88-8371-530-3) si occupa dell'accordo con i nomi collettivi a pagina 77: "il 50% degli intervistati hanno (ha) ...", "un centinaio di soci partecipano (partecipa) ...".

La conclusione del paragrafo è:

> benché si rilevi un allentamento della norma ... **nello scritto resta preferibile seguire l'accordo grammaticale, anche quando il genere e il numero logico non gli corrisponde.**

Di quel libro non trovo la data di stampa, ma è sicuramente non anteriore al 2017 (è una data riportata nelle intestazioni), quindi non direi che è obsoleto.

==============================================

Comment: Grazie. La questione mi è chiara nell'ultimo caso di "un milione di" e anche nel caso di "*n* milioni di" con un verbo coniugato con "essere", ma continuo a non sapere se ci siano due possibili scelte (con magari una più frequente dell'altra) nell'altro caso che ho esposto (predicato nominale). Per me non è tanto evidente, forse per quello che è spiegato in un commento sulle mie lingue.

Comment: @Charo a me pare che siano tutti unanimi. Treccani, commenti e me stesso (*per quello che vale, naturalmente*), nel dire che entrambe le forme sono accettabili. Molto giocano il contesto e il gusto personale; i commenti sembrano riportare che il modo "a senso" sia più usato. La mia risposta usa "il modo della Crusca", e a questo punto direi che il tuo dubbio è sbagliato, oppure irrisolvibile.

Comment: Non capisco cosa sia un "dubbio sbagliato" e non ho visto niente al riguardo dell'Accademia della Crusca.

Comment: @Charo, un dubbio "è sbagliato" quando non ci dovrebbe essere perché le risposte al dubbio esistono e sono state esaminate. In questo caso hai avuto molti pareri, se ancora non sei soddisfatta allora il dubbio è irrisolvibile. Riguardo alla Crusca, non ho detto che ne ha parlato, ho detto che io ho risposto come farebbe lei, cioè parlando molto per poi, alla fine, lasciare (a volte) insoddisfatti.

Comment: Mi dispiace @linuxfan, ma non sono d'accordo che ci siano dubbi irrisolvibili in lingua (possono essere certamente difficili da chiarire, ma non irrisolvibili). E io ho certamente questo dubbio. Ho posto una domanda in certi aspetti simile su Spanish.SE (sito su una lingua in cui certamente so come esprimermi), per il momento non ha nessuna risposta con upvote e nessuno mi ha detto che si tratti di un dubbio irresolvibile (la domanda si trova là da una settimana fa e ha avuto un certo interesse).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Interessante anche notare che lingue come l'inglese evitino questi problemi selezionando il plurale "a million people were on the street".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Cerco di spiegartelo in un altro modo. In spagnolo, la grammatica della RAE afferma che tanto "ha llegado un grupo de personas" (traduzione di "è arrivato un gruppo di persone", verbo al singolare) come "han llegado un grupo de personas" (traduzione di "sono arrivate un gruppo di persone", verbo al plurale) sono ammesse, ma che la concordanza *ad sensum* (cioè, il verbo al plurale) è più frequente.

Comment: Anche la grammatica della RAE afferma che, se la frase ha un predicato nominale, come, per esempio, "la mitad de los habitantes son analfabetos" (traduzione di "la metà degli abitanti sono analfabeti") soltanto questo modo di fare l'accordo è ammessa: non si può dire "la mitad de los habitantes es analfabeta" (traduzione di "la metà degli abitanti è analfabeta").

Comment: Allora, siccome il Treccani afferma che tanto "è venuta una massa di amici" come "sono venuti una massa di amici" sono ammessi, io dovrei vedere come ovvio che in italiano si possa dire sia "la metà degli abitanti è analfabeta" sia "la metà degli abitanti sono analfabeti"? E, se non lo vedo come tanto ovvio, allora il mio dubbio è irrisolvibile o sbagliato?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:   Il paragone con lo spagnolo l'ho fatto soltanto per farti un esempio simile in cui la "deduzione ovvia" non è tanto ovvia. E, sì, forse questo è il mio problema, l'ho avuto tutta la mia vita, fin da piccola: le cose le devo capire. E, se non le capisco, non riesco a impararle. Che venga qualcuno (non importa chi sia) e mi dica "sono così perché lo dico io, fidati di me", mi dispiace davvero, forse è utile ad altre persone, a me però non aiuta a imparare. Sarà un mio difetto di fabbrica...

Comment: @Charo qui non c'è "qualcuno che dice fidati di me", io ho scritto la risposta per riassumere i commenti; poi, visto che la materia è ambigua, ho introdotto un paio di pensiero miei, la "numeralità" e il fatto che secondo me la concordanza esatta è sempre giusta: "Un milione di persone è analfabeta" è corretto, comprensibile e naturale. A questo punto, credo, tu vuoi trovare un Serianni o Coletti o Crusca che dicano "in caso di copula si usa la concordanza xxx". E se nessun libro riporta questa frase esatta, come consideri il tuo dubbio? Risolvibile?