# Differenza tra "c'era" e "ci fu"

Tags: word-choice, difference, tenses

Voglio tradurre la seguente espressione in italiano:

> There were a number of ships

Viene da una frase che dice "there were a number of ships at the time, all used to transport supplies".

Qual è la differenza tra queste due possibili traduzioni?

> C'era un numero di navi
>
> Ci fu un numero di navi

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Can we have the context of this sentence? I believe it will be difficult to give you an answer without any context.

Comment: The article is describing a historical event. The full sentence says `that there were a number of ships at the time, all used to transport supplies'

Comment: The ships existed for a length in time, so you use the “imperfetto” *c'era*. The “passato remoto” would describe an event at a particular point in time. The translation might better be “C'era una quantità di navi, al tempo, usate per il trasporto di beni”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choosing between *imperfetto* and *passato remoto*/*passato prossimo* is sometimes difficult for people speaking languages where this distinction is missing.

English has a kind of *imperfetto* with the construction *used to* or the progressive form, but they don't fully overlap.

> I used to live in Rome when I was a student ↔ Abitavo a Roma quando studiavo
>
> I was living in Rome when I met my girlfriend ↔ Abitavo a Roma quando ho conosciuto la mia ragazza
>
> Once I was a boy ↔ Un tempo ero un bambino

Both Italian sentences have the *imperfetto*. In the third sentence there cannot be the *passato* (either *remoto* or *prossimo*), because we need to convey the idea that being a boy lasted for a period of time.

Different languages, different use of verbs.

In your sentence, the ships existed for a period of time, during which they transported supplies, so you have to use the *imperfetto*:

> Al tempo c'era una quantità di navi che trasportavano rifornimenti

I wouldn't translate “number” with *numero*, in this case, because it denotes an undetermined quantity. It could also be *un certo numero*. Yes, to express an undetermined number we use *certo*, but such usage is also common in English for “certain”. Even better (thanks to DaG)

> Al tempo c’erano numerose navi che trasportavano rifornimenti.

The problem whether the verb *trasportavano* is conjugated with the grammatical subject (*quantità*, singular) or with the logical subject (*navi*, plural) has been discussed on the site, for instance at [Is 'c'è' or 'ci sono' used with "un sacco di"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3593/70)

Comment: Or, more simply, _...c'erano numerose navi che trasportavano..._.

Comment: I may be wrong, but _ho incontrato la mia ragazza_ sounds a bit like a calque from English to me; I'd say _ho conosciuto la mia ragazza_ (or did you actually say that they already knew each other and met by chance in the street?).

Comment: @DaG Incorporated